# System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' bilgiislem.Models.Hesap.Role.get returned null

Tags: reference, null, nullreferenceexception

I have correctly established the connection between the account and the Role. I define a role for the account by typing the Id of the Role. But when I try to login to the account I get this error. I could not solve the problem. The code causing the error is:

```
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, account.Role.Name));
```

The error I get is this System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

bilgiislem.Models.Hesap.Role.get returned null.

Please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It seems like `account.Role` is `null`. Do you know how to use the debugger?

Comment: It is impossible for it to be empty because I deleted and recreated the whole database, associated it and created the tables again. The sql database seems to be full

Comment: I dont know use debugger sorry

Comment: can anyone help me

Comment: Please learn how to use the debugger. Learn how to debug.

Comment: Also if you tagged the question with [c#] you probably would have gotten a lot of people viewing this question.